# Need to merge mutiple block response into individual lines

Tags: unix

Basically i need to process XML file response which contains multiple blocks as output in a single file.So i need to convert individual blocks into separate lines in unix.

Source Data :

```
<xml.ValidateAddressResponse xmlns="http://www.pb.com/spectrum/services/ValidateAddress">
            <output_port>
            <Address>
            <Confidence>82</Confidence>
            <RecordType>Normal</RecordType>
            <CountryLevel>A</CountryLevel>
            <ProcessedBy>USA</ProcessedBy>
            <MatchScore>0</MatchScore>
            <AddressLine1>1825 Kramer Ln</AddressLine1>
            <City>Austin</City>
            <StateProvince>TX</StateProvince>
            <PostalCode>78758-4260</PostalCode>
            <PostalCode.Base>78758</PostalCode.Base>
            <PostalCode.AddOn>4260</PostalCode.AddOn>
            <Country>United States Of America</Country>
            <user_fields/>
            </Address>
            </output_port>
            </xml.ValidateAddressResponse>
<xml.ValidateAddressResponse xmlns="http://www.pb.com/spectrum/services/ValidateAddress">
            <output_port>
            <Address>
            <Confidence>82</Confidence>
            <RecordType>Normal</RecordType>
            <CountryLevel>A</CountryLevel>
            <ProcessedBy>USA</ProcessedBy>
            <MatchScore>0</MatchScore>
            <AddressLine1>1825 Kramer Ln</AddressLine1>
            <City>Austin</City>
            <StateProvince>TX</StateProvince>
            <PostalCode>78758-4260</PostalCode>
            <PostalCode.Base>78758</PostalCode.Base>
            <PostalCode.AddOn>4260</PostalCode.AddOn>
            <Country>United States Of America</Country>
            <user_fields/>
            </Address>
            </output_port>
            </xml.ValidateAddressResponse>
```

Output Needed :

```
<xml.ValidateAddressResponse xmlns="http://www.pb.com/spectrum/services/ValidateAddress"><output_port><Address><Confidence>82</Confidence><RecordType>Normal</RecordType><CountryLevel>A</CountryLevel><ProcessedBy>USA</ProcessedBy><MatchScore>0</MatchScore><AddressLine1>1825 Kramer Ln</AddressLine1><City>Austin</City><StateProvince>TX</StateProvince><PostalCode>78758-4260</PostalCode><PostalCode.Base>78758</PostalCode.Base><PostalCode.AddOn>4260</PostalCode.AddOn><Country>United States Of America</Country><user_fields/></Address></output_port></xml.ValidateAddressResponse>
<xml.ValidateAddressResponse xmlns="http://www.pb.com/spectrum/services/ValidateAddress"><output_port><Address><Confidence>82</Confidence><RecordType>Normal</RecordType><CountryLevel>A</CountryLevel><ProcessedBy>USA</ProcessedBy><MatchScore>0</MatchScore><AddressLine1>1825 Kramer Ln</AddressLine1><City>Austin</City><StateProvince>TX</StateProvince><PostalCode>78758-4260</PostalCode><PostalCode.Base>78758</PostalCode.Base><PostalCode.AddOn>4260</PostalCode.AddOn><Country>United States Of America</Country><user_fields/></Address></output_port></xml.ValidateAddressResponse>
```

Please guide me on this case.

Comment: So did you try anything? Where are you stuck exactly? Stack Overflow is not a free-programmer-for-hire website.

Comment: I have tried to merge the entire message inside the file and convert them into a single line using below two commands.Both are giving the same output

1) cat file.txt | tr -d " \t\n\r" 
2) perl -pe 's/\s+//g' file.txt

But after that i want to break the single line into multiple line based on the search string after the word '</xml.ValidateAddressResponse>' and output should be as mentioned intially.

Answer (score 0):

```
(echo v/\<xml.ValidateAddressResponse/-,.j; echo w) | ed file.txt
```